# Regular expression in python with urlParse

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, preg-match, urlparse

I have this URL:

```
https://www.yoursite.com/drive/team-real-431/pepe-ozil-R323/anyway-jim-james-hi-bye-hi-321312/;jsessionid=DBDE454034B0EE325FC100112EF2E123.56AC29295781342F53AB242D03EE33
```

i want to have

```
DBDE454034B0EE325FC100112EF2E123.56AC29295781342F53AB242D03EE33
```

i tried

```
ulrJS = "https://www.yoursite.com/drive/team-real-431/pepe-ozil-R323/anyway-jim-james-hi-bye-hi-321312/;jsessionid=DBDE454034B0EE325FC100112EF2E123.56AC29295781342F53AB242D03EE33"
ulrJS = ulrJS.split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: @Francesco thanks, i edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `urlparse`:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = 'https://www.yoursite.com/drive/team-real-431/pepe-ozil-R323/anyway-jim-james-hi-bye-hi-321312/;jsessionid=DBDE454034B0EE325FC100112EF2E123.56AC29295781342F53AB242D03EE33'
>>> url_parts = urlparse.urlparse(url)
>>> jsessionid = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(url_parts.params)).get('jsessionid')
>>> print(jsessionid)
DBDE454034B0EE325FC100112EF2E123.56AC29295781342F53AB242D03EE33
```

Comment: i use python 2.7, i got this error:     jsessionid = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(url_parts.params)).get('jsessionid')
NameError: name 'url_parts' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
from urlparse import urlparse
url ="https://www.yoursite.com/drive/team-real-431/pepe-ozil-R323/anyway-jim-james-hi-bye-hi-321312/;jsessionid=DBDE454034B0EE325FC100112EF2E123.56AC29295781342F53AB242D03EE33"
u = urlparse(url)
print u.params.split("=")[1]
'DBDE454034B0EE325FC100112EF2E123.56AC29295781342F53AB242D03EE33'
```

Comment: Better to use `urlparse.parse_qsl` just in case you have other params other than `jsessionid`.